# Seeing Emails Associated to a User in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce

In Salesforce, I am using the Salesforce Gmail extension tool to associate emails to the user object (not the contact object). But in Salesforce I can only find the email if I search for it specifically; I cannot see emails associated to a user from the user screen/form similar to how you can see related activities under a contact. Question: is there a way to see emails associated to a user object on the user screen/form? Can this feature be enabled somehow? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

it is not possible in a standard way because the email shows up that subsist in your user object  in user object all data like username password exist but I can create logic in custom apex class to do this with some triggers .its sound like integration with Gmail https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=app_for_gmail_setup_considerations.htm&type=5